# How to match the exact string value in the list of comma separated string

Tags: java, arrays, string, algorithm, search

I have around 1 million record. Which is similar to array of something like

```
String[] a1 =  {"A,B,C","C,D,E",...so on};
String[] a2 =  {"F,G,H","I,J,K",...so on};
.
.
.
String[] ax =  {"X1,X2,X3","X4,X5,X6",...so on}; //x is near to one million.
```

What is best way to find if string array contains particular word i.e A or B?

Comment: Define "best". Do you mean simplest, fastest, or something else? What have you tried to implement this quite basic functionality. What is wrong with what you tried? How is the fact that you have many arrays relevant?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by word: Is `X1,` a word? Or is a word delimited by `,`?

Comment: Yes, X1 is word, and Currently, I am taking each string array and splitting and crating multiple string arrays and searching required string within those arrays.